# Comparing file names and md5sums of multiple files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, md5sum, cmp

I'm writing a bash script that copies images from a directory (and all of its subdirectories) to another directory.

So far, I have this:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*IMG_[0-9]{4}\.jpg' -exec cp {} ~/$output \;
```

This works, but the problem is more complex than that. There are two cases:

- Some of the images have the same name, but are different. In this
  case, they are to be renamed simply by adding a second ".JPG" to the
  end of their name.
- However, if two files have the same name and are identical files,
  only one should be copied to the output directory, and the absolute
  path of the other should be written to a text file - duplicates.txt.

I'm thinking that I need to use cmp on filenames and then md5sum to check for identical files, but I'm not sure how to use cmp on filenames, or if that is even possible.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `fdupes` command might do what you want.

Comment: `cmp` tells you if files are identical, it compares byte by byte.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't entirely tested, but does this do the trick for you? Basically just loops around the output from `find`, checks the conditions you specified, and does the appropriate action. Input directory is passed as the first parameter, output as the second.

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
output=$2
logfile=~/duplicates.txt

while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do
    #strip the input directory name from the file
    f=${f/$input\//}
    echo Working with $f
    #check if the file exists
    if [ -f "$output/$f" ]; then
        if cmp -s "$input/$f" "$output/$f"; then
            #file is identical
            echo "$f" >> "$logfile"
        else
            #same filename, but different file
            cp --parents -p "$input/$f" "$output/$f.JPG"
        fi
    else
        cp --parents -p "$input/$f" "$output/$f"
    fi
done< <(find "$input" -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*IMG_[0-9]{4}\.jpg' -print0)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry it took a while to get back to you...

I've tried running your code, and it gives me 3 errors. Apparently ": command not found on line 4" (probably because there isn't a line 4)

and 2 errors on line 22, something about syntax